# symfony 2 error insert data into database null value error

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (vUsername, vEmail, vPassword, vUserPic, dCreatedDate, dModifiedDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'vUsername' cannot be null in symfony when i insert data in to table

```
INFO - Matched route "app_user_users".
INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - "START TRANSACTION"
DEBUG - INSERT INTO users (vUsername, vEmail, vPassword, vUserPic, dCreatedDate, dModifiedDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG - "ROLLBACK"
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (vUsername, vEmail, vPassword, vUserPic, dCreatedDate, dModifiedDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, null, null]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'vUsername' cannot be null" at /opt/lampp/htdocs/userpost/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".


<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\UsersType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Users;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/users")
     */   
public function usersAction(Request $request)
    {


        $users = new Users();
        $form = $this->createForm(UsersType::class, $users);


        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($users);
            $em->flush();



            return $this->redirectToRoute('register.html.twig');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'UserRegistration/register.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
            );
        }
    }
```

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class UsersType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('vUsername')
                ->add('vEmail')
                ->add('vPassword')
                ->add('vUserPic');
        }

        /**
         * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Users'
            ));
        }
    }
```

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UsersRepository")
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vUsername", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $vUsername;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vEmail", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $vEmail;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vPassword", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $vPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vUserPic", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $vUserPic;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dCreatedDate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dCreatedDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dModifiedDate", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dModifiedDate;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set vUsername
     *
     * @param string $vUsername
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setVUsername($vUsername)
    {

        $this->vUsername = $vUsername;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vUsername
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVUsername()
    {
        return $this->vUsername;
    }

    /**
     * Set vEmail
     *
     * @param string $vEmail
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setVEmail($vEmail)
    {
        $this->vEmail = $vEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vEmail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVEmail()
    {
        return $this->vEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set vPassword
     *
     * @param string $vPassword
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setVPassword($vPassword)
    {
        $this->vPassword = $vPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vPassword
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVPassword()
    {
        return $this->vPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Set vUserPic
     *
     * @param string $vUserPic
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setVUserPic($vUserPic)
    {
        $this->vUserPic = $vUserPic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vUserPic
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVUserPic()
    {
        return $this->vUserPic;
    }

    /**
     * Set dCreatedDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dCreatedDate
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setDCreatedDate($dCreatedDate)
    {
        $this->dCreatedDate = $dCreatedDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dCreatedDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDCreatedDate()
    {
        return $this->dCreatedDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set dModifiedDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dModifiedDate
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setDModifiedDate($dModifiedDate)
    {
        $this->dModifiedDate = $dModifiedDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dModifiedDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDModifiedDate()
    {
        return $this->dModifiedDate;
    }




    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $vusername;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $vemail;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $vpassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $vuserpic;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $dcreateddate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $dmodifieddate;


}
```

Comment: I think the error is clear. What you're trying to insert? Can you share your code?

Comment: Try displaying the code where you're actually doing the insertion instead of just the error message you're getting.

Comment: all the values in your query are null.  Have you handled the form properly? Please show us your controller action code.

Comment: can we see your `AppBundle\Entity\Users` class?

Comment: i will share my code

Comment: you see code of users class coad?

Comment: why have you declared $vusername, $vemail, etc., twice in your Users class?

Comment: they generate other error

Comment: any suggestions for this code?

Comment: which other error?

Comment: Property AppBundle\Entity\Users::$vusername does not exist
500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your changed you username to be nullable and forgot to update database schema (d:s:u --force).